# Reading a binary 16-bit signed (big-endian) integer in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I tried to read from a file where numbers are stored as 16-bit signed integers in big-endian format.

I used unpack to read in the number, but there is no parameter for a 16-bit signed integer in big-endian format, only for an unsigned integer. Here is what I have so far:

```
number = f.read(2).unpack('s')[0]
```

Is there a way to interpret the number above as a signed integer or another way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution that works by reading two 8bit unsigned integers and convert them to a 16bit big-endian integer

```
bytes = f.read(2).unpack('CC')  
elevation = bytes[0] << 8 | bytes[1]
```

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if it's possible to use `String#unpack` for that, but to convert a 16bit-unsigned to signed, you can use the [classical method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement#Calculating_two.27s_complement):

```
>> value = 65534
>> (value & ~(1 << 15)) - (value & (1 << 15))
=> -2
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [BinData](http://bindata.rubyforge.org) and there's no need for bit twiddling.

```
BinData::Int16be.read(io)
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently since Ruby 1.9.3 you can actually suffix the `s` with endiannes like so:

`io.read(2).unpack('s>')`